# Load .cgr files into CATIA using catscript to generate silhouettes

Tags: vb.net, catia

I am running a catscript that imports a txt file and loads .cgr files into catia to generate a 3dxml file. When this 3dxml file is opened all the cgr components are present but the product structure is flat with no multi-level nodes available. I have followed the catia documentation for adding components to generate the code. The aim of this code is to generate a part with its silhouettes(full cgrs). Here is the code:

```
  Sub CATMain()
  Dim file_name As String
  Dim RootPartNumber As String
  Dim linecount As Interger
  Dim input_level As Interger
  Dim dbinput_file as File
  Dim arrFields
  Dim dbinput_file_stream  As TextStream
  Dim iMatrix(12)
  Dim oMatrix(11)
  Dim mMatrix(2137,12)
  Dim repo_path(10000) As String
  Dim cgrpath_part(10000,10000) As String
  Dim repo_path_present As Integer
  Dim index As Integer
  Dim Str As String
  Dim ProductArray(10000) As Product
  Dim FileSysObject
  Dim Instance As Product
  Dim file_directory As String
  Dim file_extension As String
  Set FileSysObject = CATIA.FileSystem
  
  flag = false
  file_name=CATIA.SystemService.Environ("SIL_INPUTFLE")
  file_directory="/tmp/DLNAME4/"
  file_extension=".3dxml"
  'CATIA.SystemService.print "Input Argument is  " & file_name
  Dim  value as Boolean
  value=FileSysObject.FileExists(file_name)
   ' MsgBox " return value is  " & value

  If (Not CATIA.FileSystem.FileExists (file_name)) Then
      CATIA.SystemService.print "path not found  "
  End If

  Set dbinput_file = FileSysObject.GetFile(file_name)
  Set dbinput_file_stream = dbinput_file.OpenAsTextStream("ForReading")
  repo_path_present=0
  linecount=1
    

  'Create a new product document object by adding a document with the Product
  'type to the document collection of the CATIA application.

  Dim oProductDoc As Document
  Set oProductDoc = CATIA.Documents.Add("Product")

  'Retrieve the Design part as the root product.
  Dim odesign As Product
  Set odesign = oProductDoc.Product


  'Retrieve the product's collection of the Design.
  Dim odesignProducts As Products
  Set odesignProducts = odesign.Products

  ' Read a line at a time until EOF
  Dim linein As String
  linein = dbinput_file_stream.ReadLine
  Do While Not dbinput_file_stream.AtEndOfStream

  ' CATIA.SystemService.print "  value of linein is   " & linein
  arrFields = Split(linein,",")
  ' iMatrix = arrFields
  ' CATIA.SystemService.print "  value of arrFields is   " & arrFields
  'for each x in arrFields
  'For i = Lbound(arrFields) to Ubound(arrFields)

   RootPartNumber=arrFields(0)
   odesign.PartNumber=RootPartNumber
   odesign.Name = RootPartNumber


    iMatrix(0) = CDbl(arrFields(1))
    iMatrix(1) = CDbl(arrFields(2))
    iMatrix(2) = CDbl(arrFields(3))
    iMatrix(3) = CDbl(arrFields(4))
    iMatrix(4) = CDbl(arrFields(5))
    iMatrix(5) = CDbl(arrFields(6))
    iMatrix(6) = CDbl(arrFields(7))
    iMatrix(7) = CDbl(arrFields(8))
    iMatrix(8) = CDbl(arrFields(9))
    iMatrix(9) = CDbl(arrFields(10))
    iMatrix(10) =CDbl(arrFields(11))
    iMatrix(11) =CDbl(arrFields(12))
    iMatrix(12) =CDbl(arrFields(13))

' Here we are storing the cgr path is an Array repo_path and if the cgr already exsists in the array its not added then

   If linecount=1 then
     repo_path(linecount-1)=arrFields(15)
     reDim repoList(0)
     repoList(0) = arrFields(15)
   End If
   If linecount >1 then
       'CATIA.SystemService.print "looking for " & arrFields(15)
       ' CATIA.SystemService.print " line_count is " &linecount
        For index=0 to linecount-1
          If arrFields(15)=repo_path(index) then
            repo_path_present=1
            'CATIA.SystemService.print " path found  with index vlaue " & index
            Exit For
          Else
            'CATIA.SystemService.print " else "
             If linecount-1-index=1 then
              'CATIA.SystemService.print " new cgr with kvlaue " & index
               repo_path_present=0
               repo_path(index+1)=arrFields(15)
              ' CATIA.SystemService.print " new cgr with n pos " & index+1
              Exit For
            Else
              ' CATIA.SystemService.print " e1"
            End If
          End if

        Next
    End if

   flag = false
   input_level=iMatrix(0)

   If input_level=1 Then
    For j = 1 to Ubound(iMatrix)
        mMatrix(input_level,j)=iMatrix(j)
    Next
  Else
   mMatrix(input_level,1) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,1) * iMatrix(1)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,4) * iMatrix(2)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,7) * iMatrix(3))
   mMatrix(input_level,2) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,2) * iMatrix(1)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,5) * iMatrix(2)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,8) * iMatrix(3))
   mMatrix(input_level,3) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,3) * iMatrix(1)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,6) * iMatrix(2)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,9) * iMatrix(3))
   mMatrix(input_level,4) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,1) * iMatrix(4)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,4) * iMatrix(5)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,7) * iMatrix(6))
   mMatrix(input_level,5) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,2) * iMatrix(4)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,5) * iMatrix(5)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,8) * iMatrix(6))
   mMatrix(input_level,6) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,3) * iMatrix(4)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,6) * iMatrix(5)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,9) * iMatrix(6))
   mMatrix(input_level,7) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,1) * iMatrix(7)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,4) * iMatrix(8)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,7) * iMatrix(9))
   mMatrix(input_level,8) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,2) * iMatrix(7)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,5) * iMatrix(8)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,8) * iMatrix(9))
   mMatrix(input_level,9) = (mMatrix(input_level-1,3) * iMatrix(7)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,6) * iMatrix(8)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,9) * iMatrix(9))
   mMatrix(input_level,10) =(mMatrix(input_level-1,1) * iMatrix(10)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,4) * iMatrix(11)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,7) * iMatrix(12) + mMatrix(input_level-1,10))
   mMatrix(input_level,11) =(mMatrix(input_level-1,2) * iMatrix(10)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,5) * iMatrix(11)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,8) * iMatrix(12) + mMatrix(input_level-1,11))
   mMatrix(input_level,12) =(mMatrix(input_level-1,3) * iMatrix(10)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,6) * iMatrix(11)) + (mMatrix(input_level-1,9) * iMatrix(12) + mMatrix(input_level-1,12))

  End If
     ' MsgBox "  value of linecount  is   " & linecount
     ' linecount = linecount + 1

   for j = 1 to 12
   oMatrix(j-1) = mMatrix(input_level,j)
   Next
  
   ' If repo_path_present value is set to 0 then the current entry is a new product
        If repo_path_present=0 then
        ' CATIA.SystemService.print " New product "
          Dim oSIL_Prod As Product
         If InStr(arrFields(14), "/") <> 0 Then
           arrFields(14)=Replace(arrFields(14),"/","-")
         End if
            Set  oSIL_Prod = odesignProducts.AddNewProduct(arrFields(14))
            oSIL_Prod.PartNumber = arrFields(14)
            oSIL_Prod.Name = linecount

             'Add a master shape representation to the hull using an existing part and
             'reframe the viewer.
             oSIL_Prod.AddMasterShapeRepresentation arrFields(15)
            ' CATIA.ActiveWindow.ActiveViewer.Reframe
             oSIL_Prod.Move.Apply oMatrix
        End If
   'Copy the product reference is a array ProductArray 
        Set ProductArray(linecount-1)=oSIL_Prod.ReferenceProduct

   ' If repo_path_present value is set to 1 then the current entry is already present. Use Add component

        If repo_path_present=1 then
            ' CATIA.SystemService.print " New component "
             'CATIA.SystemService.print " found  with index vlaue " & index
             Set Instance= ProductArray(index)
             'Dim ProductInstance As Product
             Set ProductInstance = odesignProducts.AddComponent(Instance)
             ProductInstance.Name = linecount
             ProductInstance.Move.Apply oMatrix
             'CATIA.SystemService.print " ProductArray value is " & ProductArray(linecount-1)
        End If

     linecount= linecount + 1
     linein = dbinput_file_stream.ReadLine
  Loop
  ' Close file
  dbinput_file_stream.Close

   'Save as 3dxml file
   'oProductDoc.SaveAs file_directory & odesign.PartNumber & file_extension
    oProductDoc.ExportData file_directory & odesign.PartNumber , "3dxml"
End Sub
```

When the 3dxml file is opened it should not have a flat structure but instead have indented nodes.

Comment: According to page 7 and 8 of [this document](https://www.scripting4v5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VB-Scripting-4th-Ed-Chap-1-Preview.pdf) CATIA supports VBScript, CATScript, VB, VBA and VB.Net so you need to be more specific. One thing I’m sure of is it’s not VBScript so that leaves four other candidates.

Comment: I attempted to tag this with catscript but it didnt find a catscript tag so i couldnt, i therefore used the vbscript tag as catscript is build around this and is very similar.

Comment: However, the code posted is not VBScript and is not "very similar". However, it does look like other flavours of VB.